# How to locate/delete the view history of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Nirsoft has a software called "LastActivityView", which basically grabs all user activities from registry, event logs, etc.
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/computer_activity_view.html

Among all those activities, there is one "View Folder in Explorer". This records time, filename and full path that every time a file is viewed in Windows Explorer, dated back to the day Windows was installed. As the software itself doesn't record these, there must be somewhere these info are stored by Windows Explorer.

However, after a bit google search, I cannot find any useful information on this issue. This is not about address bar history, recent folders or Internet Explorer history.

Comment: Here's a tip: backup/export the **Bags** and **BagMRU** subkeys of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell`, then delete them and restart Windows. Does the app still find anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Explorer remembers the settings (position, size, column positions, and so on) for every folder you open by storing it under the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\ShellNoRoam 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell
```

Nirsoft LastActivityView uses the above registry keys to add the `View Folder in Explorer` event. If you delete the subkeys under the above registry keys (With `RegEdit`), Windows will "forget" the settings of all folders.